# Mojarra for JSF Encoding

Tags: jsf, encoding

Can anyone teach me how to use mojarra to encode my JSF files. I downloaded mojarra and expected some kind of jar but what i had downloaded was a folder of files i don't know what to do with

Comment: Do you mean '*Encoding* is converting the current values of the component into the corresponding markup, that is, HTML'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar` in the `lib` folder. That are the Mojarra JAR's.

By the way, I do not quite understand what you mean with "JSF encoding". That makes at its own no sense. Mojarra is just the Sun-provided basic JSF implementation.

Comment: Ah ok...Actually my real problem is accepting inputs from my Spring Faces form. The nihongo character inputs are not successfully saved in the database. What are saved are inverted question mark symbols. I believed that this is a problem with the encoding. I read that it is one of faces' issues about encoding and that an alternative is to use mojarra to solve this problem. I thought mojarra is just some knd of interceptor to convert my submitted form data to ascii

Comment: BY the way. I'm using hibernate to insert the data to the database

Comment: You have a character encoding configuration problem. JSF is a component based MVC framework. I don not quite understand how you think to solve a character encoding problem with JSF. To solve it you actually need to set everything to use `UTF-8`. Also see this link for details and solutions: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html Hope this helps.